# Why did Muni Jahnu drank entire water of holy river Ganga?

Tags: rishi, ganga, rivers

Recently at a vedic discourse I heard about this saint Jahnu who drank the entire river Ganga, so my question is:

- Why did he drink the entire river?
- What is the origin of this story?

Please cite authentic references in your answers, preferably from our scriptures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears in Bala  Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana.

After descending from Heaven on the head of Shiva and from there to Earth, Ganga started following [the course Bhagiratha took](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga43/bala_43_frame.htm).

As she inundated the field, where Sage Jahnu was performing a Vedic ritual, the latter got angry and drank the entire water of Ganga.

> ततो हि यजमानस्य जह्नोरद्भुतकर्मणः ||१-४३-३४ गङ्गा संप्लावयामास
>   यज्ञवाटं महत्मनः |
>
> While in flow she started to completely inundate the field of
>   Vedic-ritual belonging to the great-souled sage Jahnu, who is of
>   marvellous deeds and who is presently an officiator of an ongoing
>   Vedic-ritual.
>
> तस्यावलेपनं ज्ञात्वा क्रुद्धो जह्नुश्च राघव || १-४३-३५ अपिबत्तु जलं
>   सर्वं गङ्गायाः परमाद्भुतम् |
>
> But on knowing her hubris, oh, Raghava, that sage Jahnu has become
>   irritated and causing an extreme marvel he drank off all the water of
>   Ganga.

Comment: I believe that's how Ganga got her other name Jahnavi